# "playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Response body is unavailable for redirect responses" When getting the body of the response

Tags: python, playwright-python

I want to get the JSON response to a request but encounter this error. I am using playwright with python.

I am able to get the URL, Request URL, etc. But I encounter the above mentioned error whenever I try to get the body or its JSON contents.

```
def get_response_json(page: Page):

    page.goto("https://example.com")

    with page.expect_response("**example.com/api/something**") as response:
        print(response.value.body())
```

Can somebody explain to me what this error means? Is there some workaround I can use? I am using playwright because my end goal is to be able to trigger requests by clicking elements and getting the JSON response to those requests. Do I have to go down the path of remaking every request after getting its URL when I click elements and scroll?

Comment: page count might be 0

Comment: What do you mean by that? I can see the response in the network tab of browser inspector and loads up fine.

Comment: `print(response)` Is this giving anything?

Comment: I think I tried that and it didn't work or it wasn't the body of the response as I wanted, anyways, I got it to work, kinda. It kept giving me the error so I thought since it says: '_expect_response()' I figured I should do an action after which it can _expect_ the response, and, to my surprise, it worked. However, I still cannot use it since the JSON response it returns is...broken. My thinking is that it returns a truncated response as seen in the browser inspector.

Comment: Using `print(response.value.body())`, you get a python object represented as json. Try `print(json.dumps(response.value.json()))`

Comment: @sunny Please post your answer as an answer, not an edit to the post. I've removed it. The question is also missing a [mcve].